# C++ Possible to use a for loop int i = container?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Hi I am currently trying out to do this but it doesn't parse.

The code I have is:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < key.length(); x++) {
        c = key.at(x);

    }

    for (int w = c; w < ptl.length(); w += keyL) {
        cout << str[w] << endl;
    }
```

The key is gotten from argv[2] the input is "52314". What I want to do is to let the second forloop run with int w = 5, int w = 2, int w = 3, int w = 1, int w = 4. Is that possible?

Anyhelp will be awesome.

Thank You

Comment: `for ( int i = 0; i < key.length(); ++i ) { cout << str[key.at(i) - '0'] << endl; }`

Comment: It's supposed to be a transposition cipher the input doesn't comes with a whitespace.

Comment: What are `ptl`, `keyL`, and `str`?

Comment: Why do you have a second for loop? Shouldn't the operations be performed on the 1st for loop. If you have 2 loops, the value of c after the first loop will be just 4. I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: ... and James Bond lives on with this encryption. MD5?

Comment: Hi Paul it's not working. Hi Barmar, ptl is a string read from file, keyl is the keylength ie. 24123 = 5. and str is a string array to store the output of the second loop.

Comment: Hi sajas, I am not good at nested loops if I put the two loops together it will not show the cout of the second loop.

Comment: what is `key` and what is `ptl`? is `key` copied to `ptl` on loop 1? what do these loop supposed to do?

Comment: Maybe something like: `for(int i = 0; i < ptl.length(); ++i) { w = ptl[i]; /* blah blah */}`

Comment: Hi Gasim, ptl is a string read from file, key is 24123 and str is a string array to store the output of the second loop. So what happen is if c = 2 i will start from int w = 5, c = 4 i will start from int w = 4.

Comment: c=2 -> w=5. This one makes sense. c=4 -> w=4. How do you come up with that?

Comment: Because I need the char from string. For example the string is 54321. Hence I will do 5 loops using int w = 5, int w=4, int w=3....

Answer (score 0):

Well, clearly you have more code. Because the `c` you're assigning to has been defined earlier.

The first problem you''ll have is that `c` will take on the values `'5'` instead of `5`. That may look the same, but the first is a character code and the second is an integer. Now the character codes for `'0' to '9'` are consecutive, which means that `c-'0'` is the correct integer.

The second problem is that your first loop runs to completion, overwriting `c` 5 times. Only then is the *last* value used. You want to use `c` *before* it's overwritten, so do that: put the second `for` loop *directly*  after the assignment to `c`, before the `}`

Comment: Hi am I right to say you suggest    for (int x = 0; x < key.length(); x++) {
        c = key.at(x);for (int w = c; w < ptl.length(); w += keyL) {
        cout << str[w] << endl;
    }

    }

Comment: @Ray: That's the smallest change that will fix the second problem. Personally, I'd just write `for(char c: key) { for int w = c-'0'; ...`

Comment: @Ray: Yes. In the end, this is homework, and you should learn from it. We'll help if you have specific questions.

Comment: hi tried the method you shown but it says that it is a c method not c++

Comment: @Ray: Ask a new question then. But first read the exact error message, carefully. It might very well tell you what the problem is. If not, do include the error message in the question.